# How to start Activity immediately?

Tags: java, android, television

I have an activity that starts a Java method from another class. In this class I start another activity that contains a WebView to read data from a Java Script website.

I use startactivity for this. But when I run startactivity it doesn't jump into OnCreate from the activity, but only at some point later. How can I start an activity and wait for it to be processed straight away?

It doesn't work with StartActivityForResult either.

Answer (score 1):

`Activity` is starting as soon as possible always and never "immediatelly". `Activity` must initialize itself and "sync" with system (its lifecycle), which takes time, few millis on fast devices, dozens and maybe even hundreds on weak units

you aren't helping using most heavy and inefficient compontent in system - `WebView`. even more, you are executing JS in it

maybe some workaround would be to use single `Activity` and switching `Fragment`s. one `Fragment` may be native and visible on start (will be inited and rendered pretty fast), another may contain `WebView` and will be loaded on `Activity`s start, but invisible. instead `startActivity` you may then switch visiblity of `Fragment`s - one with `WebView` is in fact already loaded in memory at `Activity`s start, should appear much faster